# How to compile an example from the LLVM tutorial?

Tags: cmake, clang, llvm, clang++

I downloaded the llvm sources from github and built llvm according to this instruction https://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html.  Now I'm trying to compile the Kaleidoscope example from the third chapter of the LLVM tutorial(https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html. I used the command from the example

```
clang++ -gO 3 toy.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o toy
```

It looks strange, but clang++ did not recognize some parameters (`-std:c++17 /EHs-c- /GR-`) that `llvm-config` gave it. I replaced `-std:c++17` with `-std=c++17`, and removed the `/EHs-c-/GR-` flags. After that, I found the necessary system libraries on my computer (`psapi.lib`, `shell32.lib`, `ole32.lib`, `uuid.lib`, `advapi32.lib`) and copied it to the folder with the code from the example. Then I started `clang++` and compilation was interrupted due to "fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved external issues". I've been trying to solve this problem for two days now and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

---

Here are some of the compiler error messages:

```
LLVMSupport.lib(regcomp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_toupper referenced in function ordinary
LLVMSupport.lib(JSON.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_modf referenced in function "public: class std::optional<__int64> __cdecl llvm::json::Value::getAsInteger(void)const " (?getAsInteger@Value@json@llvm@@QEBA?AV?$optional@_J@std@@XZ)
LLVMSupport.lib(JSON.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strtoll referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl llvm::json::`anonymous namespace'::Parser::parseNumber(char,class llvm::json::Value &)" (?parseNumber@Parser@?A0xaa888d9a@json@llvm@@AEAA_NDAEAVValue@34@@Z)
LLVMSupport.lib(JSON.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_strtoull referenced in function "private: bool __cdecl llvm::json::`anonymous namespace'::Parser::parseNumber(char,class llvm::json::Value &)" (?parseNumber@Parser@?A0xaa888d9a@json@llvm@@AEAA_NDAEAVValue@34@@Z)
LLVMSupport.lib(Threading.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__beginthreadex referenced in function "void * __cdecl llvm::llvm_execute_on_thread_impl(unsigned int (__cdecl*)(void *),void *,class std::optional<unsigned int>)" (?llvm_execute_on_thread_impl@llvm@@YAPEAXP6AIPEAX@Z0V?$optional@I@std@@@Z)
```

Comment: 'compilation was interrupted due to "fatal error LNK1120: 20 unresolved external issues"'-  It should output which exact functions are unresolved. Add this output to the question post.